# How can I filter files named according to Apple picture?

Tags: apple

Apple picture files in `Pictures/Photos\ Library.photoslibrary` are named e.g. `3EB45A6A...` or full example

```
0FF3D6BD-3A1D-48FD-BA12-AF4B6A49D96E.png
```

Now after some backup recovery, I have a directory where I'd like to separate the files from the picture files from other files, for example
the following files should be moved somewhere else

```
./a892_m.jpg
./dungeon1 copy.jpg
./caustics copy 2.jpg
./400149700472_354474.jpg
./engineering copy 2.jpg
```

The files are all at the same level in the same directory.

Comment: This might be impossible to do. Checking my own `Photos Library.photoslibrary` content shows files named similarly (`2A733FFE-C52D-48BC-8F51-79F4A774ABFD_4_5005_c.jpeg`) but if I run `exiftool` from the terminal to check metadata, I see lots of data but not original filename. You can install `exiftool` via [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) like this if you care to check for yourself: `brew install exiftool`